# Akka stream for posting data expects a graph not a flow in via

Tags: scala, akka-http, akka-stream

I'm trying to create an example akka stream that takes a CSV file, changes it to XML (using an already existing object which has a toXml function) and then posts this to an endpoint. The code I have created looks like this:-

```
val poolClientFlow =
  Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[Thing]("localhost",5000)

val file = new File("./example.csv")

val uploadPipeline =
  FileIO.fromFile(file)
    .via(Framing.delimiter(ByteString("\n"), maximumFrameLength = 1024))
    .map(_.utf8String)
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(t => Thing(t(0),t(1).toInt,t(2).toInt) )
    .map(_.toXml)
    .map(_.toString)
    .map(ByteString(_))
    .map(d =>HttpRequest(method=HttpMethods.POST,uri=s"/import",entity = d))
    .via(poolClientFlow)
    .runForeach(x => System.out.println(x.toString()))
```

However it doesn't compile as the call to `.via(poolClientFlow)` as it found a `akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[(akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest, com.cogpp.exp.Thing),(scala.util.Try[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpResponse],` but this version of via expects a `akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.FlowShape[akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpRequest,?],?]`.

I think I have not constructed my `poolClientFlow` correctly, but I don't see the difference between what I have done, and what I've seen in other example code. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flow from `cachedHostConnectionPool[T]` takes a tuple of `(HttpRequest,T)` This lets you keep some context of your request when you eventually get the result as `(Try[HttpResponse], T)`. If you dont need that just pass in Unit `()`.

Im not sure if there is an API that just takes the Request.

To get your example compiling you can ..

```
.map(d => (HttpRequest(method=HttpMethods.POST,uri=s"/import",entity = d), d))
.via(Http().cachedHostConnectionPool[ByteString]("localhost",5000))
```

Also if I where you I wouldnt have quite so many `.map`'s in that code. Your  serialising isnt blocking and doesnt really need the back pressure between all of those steps. I'd have a pure function `def write(t: Thing): HttpRequest`. But thats no big deal...

Comment: Thanks! That's fixed it! I think you are right about having so many maps, it's probably just adding overhead.